# Change of cell coulor (data from another sheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 sheets in a workbook.

Sheet1 contains 30 columns (month wise) & 36 rows this data is numeric format.
Sheet2 has same columns & rows filled with data.

Whenever I manually enter data in sheet1 then automatically sheet2 particular data should change in colour.

Comment: what is your question? Please read [ask] before asking.

Comment: @OP: what did you already try? Where did you run into problem. Also see user 99572 is fine's comment.